# Chaining Static Methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

Is it possible to chain static methods together using a static class? Say I wanted to do something like this:

```
$value = TestClass::toValue(5)::add(3)::subtract(2)::add(8)::result();
```

. . . and obviously I would want $value to be assigned the number 14. Is this possible?

**Update**: It doesn't work (you can't return "self" - it's not an instance!), but this is where my thoughts have taken me:

```
class TestClass {
    public static $currentValue;

    public static function toValue($value) {
        self::$currentValue = $value;
    }

    public static function add($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue + $value;
        return self;
    }

    public static function subtract($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue - $value;
        return self;
    }

    public static function result() {
        return self::$value;
    }
}
```

After working that out, I think it would just make more sense to simply work with a class instance rather than trying to chain static function calls (which doesn't look possible, unless the above example could be tweaked somehow).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I like the solution provided by Camilo above, essentially since all you're doing is altering the value of a static member, and since you do want chaining (even though it's only syntatic sugar), then instantiating TestClass is probably the best way to go.

I'd suggest a Singleton pattern if you want to restrict instantiation of the class:

```
class TestClass
{   
    public static $currentValue;

    private static $_instance = null;

    private function __construct () { }

    public static function getInstance ()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function toValue($value) {
        self::$currentValue = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function add($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue + $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function subtract($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue - $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function result() {
        return self::$currentValue;
    }
}

// Example Usage:
$result = TestClass::getInstance ()
    ->toValue(5)
    ->add(3)
    ->subtract(2)
    ->add(8)
    ->result();
```

Comment: `public function result() {
                return $this::$value;
        }
` is this line meant to be 
`public function result() {
                return $this::$currentValue;
        }
` ????

Comment: This won't work as soon as you want to use more than one together.
    `$a = TestClass::getInstance()->toValue(3)->add(5);`
    `$b = TestClass::getInstance()->toValue(7)->add($a->result());`
    `echo $b->result();`
You'll get 14 instead of 15. Don't handle money with that math.

Comment: The constructor definition `private __construct () { }` should be `private function __construct () { }`. Also, `return $this::$currentValue;` should be `return self::$currentValue;`.

Comment: I also found that this doesn't chain passed one method. Also this won't work if you use the keyword `final` on your class.

Answer (score 51):

```
class oop{
    public static $val;

    public static function add($var){
        static::$val+=$var;
        return new static;
    }

    public static function sub($var){
        static::$val-=$var;
        return new static;
    }

    public static function out(){
        return static::$val;
    }

    public static function init($var){
        static::$val=$var;
        return new static;      
    }
}

echo oop::init(5)->add(2)->out();
```

Comment: I think, when it comes to syntax (not to best coding practises), this is the best answer for this question.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: does it effect on perfomance?

Answer (score 32):

Little crazy code on php5.3... just for fun.

```
namespace chaining;
class chain
    {
    static public function one()
        {return get_called_class();}

    static public function two()
        {return get_called_class();}
    }

${${${${chain::one()} = chain::two()}::one()}::two()}::one();
```

Comment: PHP8, still working: https://3v4l.org/kTY8g

Answer (score 26):

With php7 you will be able to use desired syntax because of new [Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax)

```
<?php

abstract class TestClass {

    public static $currentValue;

    public static function toValue($value) {
        self::$currentValue = $value;
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public static function add($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue + $value;
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public static function subtract($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue - $value;
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public static function result() {
        return self::$currentValue;
    }

}

$value = TestClass::toValue(5)::add(3)::subtract(2)::add(8)::result();
echo $value;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XH42Y)

Answer (score 11):

If toValue(x) returns an object, you could do like this:

```
$value = TestClass::toValue(5)->add(3)->substract(2)->add(8);
```

Providing that toValue returns a new instance of the object, and each next method mutates it, returning an instance of $this.

Answer (score 6):

This is more accurate, easier, and read-friendly (allows code-completion)

```
class Calculator
{   
    public static $value = 0;

    protected static $onlyInstance;

    protected function __construct () 
    {
        // disable creation of public instances 
    }

    protected static function getself()
    {
        if (static::$onlyInstance === null) 
        {
            static::$onlyInstance = new Calculator;
        }

        return static::$onlyInstance;
    }

    /**
     * add to value
     * @param numeric $num 
     * @return \Calculator
     */
    public static function add($num) 
    {
        static::$value += $num;
        return static::getself();
    }

    /**
     * substruct
     * @param string $num
     * @return \Calculator
     */
    public static function subtract($num) 
    {
        static::$value -= $num;
        return static::getself();
    }

    /**
     * multiple by
     * @param string $num
     * @return \Calculator
     */
    public static function multiple($num) 
    {
        static::$value *= $num;
        return static::getself();
    }

    /**
     * devide by
     * @param string $num
     * @return \Calculator
     */
    public static function devide($num) 
    {
        static::$value /= $num;
        return static::getself();
    }

    public static function result()
    {
        return static::$value;
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
echo Calculator::add(5)
        ->subtract(2)
        ->multiple(2.1)
        ->devide(10)
    ->result();
```

**result: 0.63**

Answer (score 5):

People are overcomplicating this like crazy.

Check this out:

```
class OopClass
{
    public $first;
    public $second;
    public $third;

    public static function make($first)
    {
        return new OopClass($first);
    }

    public function __construct($first)
    {
        $this->first = $first;
    }

    public function second($second)
    {
        $this->second = $second;
        return $this;
    }

    public function third($third)
    {
        $this->third = $third;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
OopClass::make('Hello')->second('To')->third('World');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the First method as a static and the remaining as instance methods:

```
$value = Math::toValue(5)->add(3)->subtract(2)->add(8)->result();
```

Or better yet:

```
 $value = Math::eval(Math::value(5)->add(3)->subtract(2)->add(8));

class Math {
     public $operation;
     public $operationValue;
     public $args;
     public $allOperations = array();

     public function __construct($aOperation, $aValue, $theArgs)
     {
       $this->operation = $aOperation;
       $this->operationValue = $aValue;
       $this->args = $theArgs;
     }

     public static function eval($math) {
       if(strcasecmp(get_class($math), "Math") == 0){
            $newValue = $math->operationValue;
            foreach ($math->allOperations as $operationKey=>$currentOperation) {
                switch($currentOperation->operation){
                    case "add":
                         $newvalue = $currentOperation->operationValue + $currentOperation->args;
                         break;
                    case "subtract":
                         $newvalue = $currentOperation->operationValue - $currentOperation->args;
                         break;
                }
            }
            return $newValue;
       }
       return null;
     }

     public function add($number){
         $math = new Math("add", null, $number);
         $this->allOperations[count($this->allOperations)] &= $math;
         return $this;
     }

     public function subtract($number){
         $math = new Math("subtract", null, $number);
         $this->allOperations[count($this->allOperations)] &= $math;
         return $this;
     }

     public static function value($number){
         return new Math("value", $number, null);
     }
 }
```

Just an FYI.. I wrote this off the top of my head (right here on the site). So, it may not run, but that is the idea. I could have also did a recursive method call to eval, but I thought this may be simpler. Please let me know if you would like me to elaborate or provide any other help.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can call a static method on an instance like `$object::method()` in PHP 7+, so returning a new instance should work as a replacement for `return self`. [And indeed it works.](https://3v4l.org/BspcC)

```
final class TestClass {
    public static $currentValue;

    public static function toValue($value) {
        self::$currentValue = $value;
        return new static();
    }

    public static function add($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue + $value;
        return new static();
    }

    public static function subtract($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue - $value;
        return new static();
    }

    public static function result() {
        return self::$currentValue;
    }
}

$value = TestClass::toValue(5)::add(3)::subtract(2)::add(8)::result();

var_dump($value);
```

Outputs `int(14)`.

This about same as returning `__CLASS__` as used [in other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49113525/93540). I rather hope no-one ever decides to actually use these forms of API, but you asked for it.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell... no. :)  The resolution operator (::) would work for the TetsClass::toValue(5) part, but everything after that will just give a syntax error.

Once namespaces are implemented in 5.3, you can have "chained" :: operators, but all that'll do is drill down through the namespace tree; it won't be possible to have methods in the middle of things like this.

Answer (score 1):

**The best that can be done**

```
class S
{
    public static function  __callStatic($name,$args)
    {
        echo 'called S::'.$name . '( )<p>';
        return '_t';
    }
}

$_t='S';
${${S::X()}::F()}::C();
```

Comment: this is way back php5.4?

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. The `::` operator needs to evaluate back to a class, so after the `TestClass::toValue(5)` evaluates, the `::add(3)` method would only be able to evaluate on the answer of the last one.

So if `toValue(5)` returned the integer 5, you would basically be calling `int(5)::add(3)` which obviously is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way i have ever found for method chaining from new Instance or Static method of class is as below. I have used Late Static Binding here and i really loved this solution.

I have created a utility to send multiple User Notification on next page using tostr in Laravel.

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

use Session;

use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;

class Toaster
{
    private static $options = [

        "closeButton" => false,

        "debug" => false,

        "newestOnTop" => false,

        "progressBar" => false,

        "positionClass" => "toast-top-right",

        "preventDuplicates" => false,

        "onclick" => null,

        "showDuration" => "3000",

        "hideDuration" => "1000",

        "timeOut" => "5000",

        "extendedTimeOut" => "1000",

        "showEasing" => "swing",

        "hideEasing" => "linear",

        "showMethod" => "fadeIn",

        "hideMethod" => "fadeOut"
    ];

    private static $toastType = "success";

    private static $instance;

    private static $title;

    private static $message;

    private static $toastTypes = ["success", "info", "warning", "error"];

    public function __construct($options = [])
    {
        self::$options = array_merge(self::$options, $options);
    }

    public static function setOptions(array $options = [])
    {
        self::$options = array_merge(self::$options, $options);

        return self::getInstance();
    }

    public static function setOption($option, $value)
    {
        self::$options[$option] = $value;

        return self::getInstance();
    }

    private static function getInstance()
    {
        if(empty(self::$instance) || self::$instance === null)
        {
            self::setInstance();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private static function setInstance()
    {
        self::$instance = new static();
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        if(in_array($method, self::$toastTypes))
        {
            self::$toastType = $method;

            return self::getInstance()->initToast($method, $args);
        }

        throw new \Exception("Ohh my god. That toast doesn't exists.");
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return self::__callStatic($method, $args);
    }

    private function initToast($method, $params=[])
    {
        if(count($params)==2)
        {
            self::$title = $params[0];

            self::$message = $params[1];
        }
        elseif(count($params)==1)
        {
            self::$title = ucfirst($method);

            self::$message = $params[0];
        }

        $toasters = [];

        if(Session::has('toasters'))
        {
            $toasters = Session::get('toasters');
        }

        $toast = [

            "options" => self::$options,

            "type" => self::$toastType,

            "title" => self::$title,

            "message" => self::$message
        ];

        $toasters[] = $toast;

        Session::forget('toasters');

        Session::put('toasters', $toasters);

        return $this;
    }

    public static function renderToasters()
    {
        $toasters = Session::get('toasters');

        $string = '';

        if(!empty($toasters))
        {
            $string .= '<script type="application/javascript">';

            $string .= "$(function() {\n";

            foreach ($toasters as $toast)
            {
                $string .= "\n toastr.options = " . json_encode($toast['options'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . ";";

                $string .= "\n toastr['{$toast['type']}']('{$toast['message']}', '{$toast['title']}');";
            }

            $string .= "\n});";

            $string .= '</script>';
        }

        Session::forget('toasters');

        return new HtmlString($string);
    }
}
```

This will work as below.

```
Toaster::success("Success Message", "Success Title")

    ->setOption('showDuration', 5000)

    ->warning("Warning Message", "Warning Title")

    ->error("Error Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully functional example of method chaining with static attributes:

```
<?php


class Response
{
    static protected $headers = [];
    static protected $http_code = 200;
    static protected $http_code_msg = '';
    static protected $instance = NULL;


    protected function __construct() { }

    static function getInstance(){
        if(static::$instance == NULL){
            static::$instance = new static();
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

    public function addHeaders(array $headers)
    {
        static::$headers = $headers;
        return static::getInstance();
    }

    public function addHeader(string $header)
    {
        static::$headers[] = $header;
        return static::getInstance();
    }

    public function code(int $http_code, string $msg = NULL)
    {
        static::$http_code_msg = $msg;
        static::$http_code = $http_code;
        return static::getInstance();
    }

    public function send($data, int $http_code = NULL){
        $http_code = $http_code != NULL ? $http_code : static::$http_code;

        if ($http_code != NULL)
            header(trim("HTTP/1.0 ".$http_code.' '.static::$http_code_msg));

        if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
            $data = json_encode($data);

        echo $data; 
        exit();     
    }

    function sendError(string $msg_error, int $http_code = null){
        $this->send(['error' => $msg_error], $http_code);
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
Response::getInstance()->code(400)->sendError("Lacks id in request");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way without going through a `getInstance` method (tested on PHP 7.x):

```php
class TestClass
{
    private $result = 0;

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return $this->call($method, $args);
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        return (new static())->call($method, $args);
    }

    private function call($method, $args)
    {
        if (! method_exists($this , '_' . $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Call undefined method ' . $method);
        }

        return $this->{'_' . $method}(...$args);
    }

    private function _add($num)
    {
        $this->result += $num;

        return $this;
    }

    private function _subtract($num)
    {
        $this->result -= $num;

        return $this;
    }

    public function result()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

The class can be used as following:

```php
$res1 = TestClass::add(5)
    ->add(3)
    ->subtract(2)
    ->add(8)
    ->result();

echo $res1 . PHP_EOL; // 14

$res2 = TestClass::subtract(1)->add(10)->result();
echo $res2 . PHP_EOL; // 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Also works as:

```
ExampleClass::withBanners()->withoutTranslations()->collection($values)
```

Using `new static(self::class);`

```
public static function withoutTranslations(): self
{
    self::$withoutTranslations = true;
    
    return new static(self::class);
}

public static function withBanners(): self
{
    return new static(self::class);
}

public static function collection(values): self
{
    return $values;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP 7! If your web provider cannot --> change provider! Don't lock in past.

```
final class TestClass {
    public static $currentValue;

    public static function toValue($value) {
        self::$currentValue = $value;
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public static function add($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue + $value;
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public static function subtract($value) {
        self::$currentValue = self::$currentValue - $value;
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public static function result() {
        return self::$currentValue;
    }
}
```

[And very simple use:](https://3v4l.org/iipko)

```
$value = TestClass::toValue(5)::add(3)::subtract(2)::add(8)::result();

var_dump($value);
```

Return (or throw error):

```
int(14)
```

**completed contract.**

Rule one: most evolved and maintainable is always better.