# PHP OOP: Method Chaining

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

I have the following code,

```
<?php
class Templater
{
    static $params = array();

    public static function assign($name, $value)
    {
        self::$params[] = array($name => $value);
    }

    public static function draw()
    {
        self::$params;
    }
}


 $test = Templater::assign('key', 'value');
 $test = Templater::draw();
 print_r($test);
```

How can I alter this script so I could use this?

```
$test = Templater::assign('key', 'value')->assign('key2', 'value2')->draw();
print_r($test);
```

Comment: You may also want to modify the assign() method so it can accept an array of key => values.

Comment: You should be more precise in what you really want to do. Does a simple associative array served your purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use [Method Chaining](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html) with static methods because you cannot return a class level scope (`return self` won't do). Change your methods to regular methods and `return $this` in each method you want to allow chaining from.

Notice that you should not use `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` to access instance methods as it will raise an `E_STRICT` Notice. Use `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` for calling instance methods.

Also see:

- [Chaining Static Methods in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125268/chaining-static-methods-in-php)

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using static members:

```
class Templater
{
    private array $params = [];

    public function assign($name, $value) : self
    {
        $this->params[$name] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        // do something with $this->params
    }
}

$test = (new Templater())->assign('key', 'value')->assign('key2', 'value2')->draw();
```

Comment: you can't chain off of a constructor like that!

Answer (score 3):

Just use instance variables and instance functions instead of static ones.

```
<?php
class Templater
{
    $params = array();

    public function assign($name, $value)
    {
        $this->params[] = array($name => $value); 
        return $this;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        echo $this->params;
        return $this;
    }
}

$test = new Templater();
$test->assign('key', 'value')->assign('key2', 'value2')->draw();
print_r($test);
```

Comment: You need to add "return $this;" at the end of the assign() method otherwise the chaining won't work.

Answer (score 1):

////////

class Templater
{
    static $params = array();

```
public static function assign($name, $value)
{
    self::$params[] = array($name => $value);
    return new Templater;
}

public static function draw()
{
    return self::$params;
}
```

}

$test = Templater::assign('key', 'value')->assign('key2', 'value2')->draw();
print_r($test);

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation and proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing a static and an instance call like that is poor form in general, omitting that one (unless you give a reason that it needs to be static). The other concept you're working with is call chaining, which is implemented using returns.

```
class Templater
{
    protected $params = array();

    public function assign($name, $value) {
        $this->params[] = array($name => $value);
        return $this;
    }

    public function draw() {
        // do drawing w/ $this->params;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Templater
{   
    public static $params;

    private static $_instance = null;

    public static function init()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === null)
        {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function assign($name, $value)
    {
        self::$params[$name] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        return self::$params;
    }
}

$test = Templater::init()->assign('key', 'value')->assign('key2', 'value2')->draw();
```