# PHP OOP - How to call main function and sub function

Tags: php

I have to learn about OOP chaining:

```
$data = new myclass;
$data->sub_function()->main_function();
```

But now I want to code it looks like this:

```
$data = new myclass;
$main = $data->main_function();
$sub = $main->sub_function();
```

If so how would write the class functions for this?

Please help me!

Comment: The other way around... so: 
$data = new myclass;
$sub = $data->sub_function();
$main = $sub->main_function();
Since this is exactly equal to your first post, only you're using a temporary variable instead of directly chaining it

Comment: These may help you,

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990952/php-oop-method-chaining
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125268/chaining-static-methods-in-php

Comment: Using a `fluent interface`: sub_function() must return `$this`

Comment: Thanks! But i need return string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class myclass {

    public function main_function() {
        //Do your actions here
        return $this;
    }

    public function sub_function() {
        //Do your actions here
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class myclass {
    public function main_function() {
        return 'MAIN ';
    }
    public function sub_function($str) {
        if ($str == 1) $result = 'SELECT 1';
        else if ($str == 2) $result = 'SELECT 2';
        else $result = 'NOT FOUND';
        return $result;
    }
}
$data = new myclass;
$main = $data->main_function();
$sub = $main->sub_function(1);
echo $sub; // Fatal error: Call to a member function sub_function() on a non-object...
```

I need return string in each functions (not set value/key)

Comment: Because `$main` is just the string `MAIN`, try `$data->sub_function(1);`

Comment: Also, this should have been an edit to your original post, not an answer

Comment: Thanks, but id need `$data->main_function()->sub_function`

Comment: The only way you could do that is if `main_function()` returned `$this`, otherwise you're trying to run `sub_function` on a string, not your class. If you show us more of what you're trying to do we might be able to help more.