# How to combine lines of code into one line?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 lines of code here but i want to combine all 2 lines into 1

```
// How to combine these 2 lines here
$product = $this->productService->searchProduct($request);
$product = Product::paginate(9);
```

Controller:

```
public function searchProduct(SearchProductRequest $request)
    {
        $search = $request->search;

        $min_price = $request->min_price;
        $max_price = $request->max_price;

        $product = Product::query('products')
            ->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->where('price', [$min_price])
            ->orWhere('price',[$max_price])
            ->orderBy('id');

return $product;
}
```

Comment: provide searchProduct method code also

Comment: have you tried $product = $this->productService->searchProduct($request)->paginate(9); ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$product = $product::paginate(9);` ?

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to do so?

Comment: I actually tried ```  $product = $this->productService->searchProduct($request)->paginate(9); ``` but my page can not show the product list so i think that my model did not access the database

Comment: @kato.may be your query failed,try changing query  $product = Product::query('products')
   ->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
   ->whereBetween('price', [$min_price,$max_price])
  
   ->orderBy('id');

Comment: No, my query is fine, the problem is my page can search but it can not show the product list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2990952/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public function searchProduct(SearchProductRequest $request)
    {
        $products = Product::select('id', 'name', 'price')
            ->when($request->input('search'), function($q){
                $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . request()->input('search') . '%');
            })
            ->when($request->input('min_price'), function($q){
                $q->where('price', request()->input('min_price'));
            })
            ->when($request->input('max_price'), function($q){
                $q->orWhere('price', request()->input('max_price'));
            })
            ->orderBy('id')
            ->paginate(9);

        return $products;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
$product = $this->productService->searchProduct($request)->paginate(9);
```

take a look at your view blade, have you added links();
like this

```
  <div class="float-left mr-3 mb-1">
         {{ $product->links()  }}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = !empty($this->productService->searchProduct($request)?Product::paginate(9):'';
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.