# Why is it not possible to return self in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, static

In PHP it's not possible to [return self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125268/chaining-static-methods-in-php) to chain static methods. This limits the usage of static methods, because chaining is pretty useful and you have to use instances to chain methods.

Are there any reasons why the PHP developers decided not to allow returning `self`? Or is it not possible to return `self` in OOP in general?

Comment: to be honest, chaining is being overused to the point of impacting readability because everyone seems to think that the purpose of clean readable code is to make the longest chain possible (in a similar way people used to think that nested ternaries where cool); anyways, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125268/chaining-static-methods-in-php

Comment: I think that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: If you need to chain static methods then you probably have made some design mistake.

Comment: @Crozin Can you explain that a bit more? Maybe I understood some OOP concepts wrong.

Comment: Complely agree. Keep you top level interacting with the objects but never any deeper than that (or at least avoid it). Otherwise you'll end up with Spaghetti objects and a maintainence mess when you alter object structures later on.

Comment: FYI: when you are using static methods, it is not OOP. That you do is "class oriented programming". Basically, you are using global variables in simple functions , which have been wrapped in a namespace ( which is just masked as declaration of class ).

Answer (score 7):

Try `return new static()` or `return new self()`:

```
class Calculator
{
    private static $_var = 0;

    public static function startFrom($var)
    {
        self::$_var = $var;
        return new static();
    }

    public static function add($var)
    {
        self::$_var += $var;
        return new static();
    }

    public static function sub($var)
    {
        self::$_var -= $var;
        return new static();
    }

    public static function get()
    {
        return self::$_var;
    }
}
```

This could be used for chain static methods:

```
echo Calculator::startFrom(10)
    ->add(5)
    ->sub(10)
    ->get(); // return 5
```

> [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot give you a reason *why* other than the syntax itself isn't supported. It almost could work in PHP 5.3:

```
class Foo
{
  public static function A()
  {
    return __CLASS__;
  }

  public static function B() { }
}

$chain = Foo::A();
$chain::B();
```

If PHP would parse `Foo::A()::B()` then it would work.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a 'self' because no OOP language I know allows to return a type as a type (don't know how to rephrase that). However everyone allows to returns an **instance** of a type. A static method is part of a class definition and it is callable as long as the application runs.

When doing OOP, you should use the static keyword very carefuly, as it's very easy to abuse it. If you want to chain methods then use an object. Static methods should be used **only** when no state is required and the function simply process an input and returns a result.

When chaining you have to maintain state and that's where you don't use static classes/methods at all (ok there are some cases but those are exceptions and it's not the case here).

Comment: In Python or Ruby, `return cls/self` works just fine in class methods (because actually classes are first-class objects themselves in these and many other languages).

Comment: I don't know python nor ruby :). However is still strange to me to return the static class as itself, only to save typing a few characters?!

Comment: MikeSW: I didn't say it would be sensible to do that, but it should at least be possible in object-based languages (object-based as in everything is an object, including types).

Answer (score 1):

If you really had to, you can use `self::class`:

```php
class Foo
{
    public static function returnSelfClass(): string
    {
        return self::class;
    }
}
```

You can even use `static::class` for [late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

```php
class Bar
{
    public static function returnStaticClass(): string
    {
        return static::class;
    }
}

class Baz extends Bar
{
}
```

For instance:

```php
Foo::returnSelfClass()::returnSelfClass(); // Works
echo Baz::returnStaticClass(); // Prints "Baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7.0 forward, this works

```
class test {
    public static function a(){
        echo 1;
        return __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function b(){
        echo 2;
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

test::a()::b();
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody that had no relationship to you asked you to give up yourself and return yourself to something that didn't exist how would you feel?

Comment: Luckily PHP hasn't got any feelings, since it gets told a few million times a day to `die()`.