# Using class name from a static constant statically in PHP

Tags: php, static-variables

I have the class name `Car` stored as a static variable in constants. I would like to use this constant to call the function `a`. One options is to use an intermediate variable `$tmp`. I could then call `$tmp::a()`. Is there a way to do this in one statement? My attempt is below.

```
class Car{
    public static function a(){
        return 'hi';
    }
}

class Constants{
    public static $use='Car';
}

$tmp=Constants::$use;

echo(${Constants::$use}::a());
```

[IDEOne link](http://ideone.com/HXGnyC)

Output is as follows

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Car in /home/mU9w5e/prog.php on line 15
PHP Fatal error:  Class name must be a valid object or a string in /home/mU9w5e/prog.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is always [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func):

```
echo call_user_func( array( Constants::$use, 'a'));
```

[IDEOne Demo](https://ideone.com/SNU2Jp)

Answer (score 3):

The only alternative that I could find to [@nickb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862594/nickb)'s way was using something I've never heard of, but hey that's what SO is for!

I found the [ReflectionMethod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php), which seems to be more bloated than the `call_user_func`, but was the only alternative way that I could find:

```
<?php
class Car{
    public static function a(){
        return 'hi';
    }
}

class Constants{
    public static $use='Car';
}
$reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(Constants::$use, 'a');
echo $reflectionMethod->invoke(new Car());
```

The above is a bit of a failed experiment as [Casebash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165495/casebash) doesn't want to create temp variables.

As [CORRUPT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2269749/corrupt) mentioned in the comments, it is possible to use the following although was tested on `PHP version 5.4.14` (which I am unable to do):

```
echo (new ReflectionMethod(Constants::$use, 'a'))->invoke(new Car());
```

Comment: 1 line: `echo (new ReflectionMethod(Constants::$use, 'a'))->invoke(Constants::$use);`

Comment: :] , but production server very rarely upgraded. Unfortunately(

Comment: It should be noted that the overhead to do this is massive compared to a simpler approach. Reflection, two new objects, and invoking a static method on an object are all reasons to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

I have crazy solution, but you should never use it :^ )

```
echo ${${Constants::$use} = Constants::$use}::a();
```

Comment: Holy s*!t. :)) I tried something like this, but never managed to get normal results.

Comment: @CORRUPT, look at my [relative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11338446/1503018) about static calling.