# Static method that calls itself on an object

Tags: php, oop

I want to have a class that i can use it this way:

```
Thing::doThis()->doThat()->doImportantThing();
```

OR

```
Thing::doThat()->doImportantThing();
```

OR

```
Thing::doImportantThing();
```

But currently i can only use it this way:

```
$thing = new Thing();
$thing->doThis()->doThat()->doImportantThing();
```

What do i have to change in the class so i can use it the way i want? I already return a `Thing` instance in every function call.

I want to use that for a simple reason, imagine a mail class, in the constructor you define a default from and to, but you might want to change it, so you do `Mail::setFrom()->send()`. If you want to change the to, you use `Mail::setTo()->send()`. It just makes it easier to use if it's going to be used in different projects by different people.

I want by calling `Mail::{something}` to have like a constructor call and then run the `{something}` function.

Comment: I couldn't help but wonder, why?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125268/chaining-static-methods-in-php) will help somehow

Comment: @Sami Thank you, but that question partially helps, but what i want to achieve, by that example, is avoid the `getInstance()` call.

Comment: The real answer to this question is to tell you to stop using static methods.

Comment: @PeeHaa Why should i?

Comment: Well for one because you need an instance here (in any sane setup). More important it most likely produces tightly coupled code, hides dependencies, is a maintenance and debugging nightmare and kills testability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
class Thing {

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments){
        $thing = new self;
        return $thing->$name($arguments);
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        return $this->$name($arguments);
    }

    private function doThis(){
        echo 'this'.PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }

    private function doThat(){
        echo 'that'.PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }

    private function doImportantThing(){
        echo 'Important'.PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }
}

Thing::doThis()->doThat();
Thing::doThat()->doImportantThing();
```

It is a really ugly work-around, though. And it disables you to have private methods.

*[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83d8b4584317e19c5b2f39ed849efe25bbd87da8)*

Comment: I want to use that for a simple reason, imagine a mail class, in the constructor you define a default `from` and `to`, but you might want to change it, so you do `Mail::setFrom()->send()`. If you want to change the to, you use `Mail::setTo()->send()`. It just makes it easier to use if it's going to be used in different projects by different people.

Comment: So you would like to do method chaining, or just static calling?

Comment: @MichelTomé why not just pass optional parameters to the `send()` method?

Comment: Both, it's kind of hard to explain... I want by calling `Mail::{something}` to have like a constructor call and then run the `{something}` function

Comment: @MichelTomé: I added your explanations to the question, I think it's clearer now.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I suggested and edit to the code, does it work that way?

Answer (score 0):

One great thing for static methods is that they can work in object context, and can be called like this: `$instance->staticMethod()`

Here it is (even you get code completion in ide, and works as axpected as you want):

```
class Mail
{   
    public static $from;
    public static $to;
    public static $subject;
    public static $message;

    protected static $onlyInstance;

    protected function __construct () 
    {
        // disable creation of public instances 
    }

    protected static function getself()
    {
        if (static::$onlyInstance === null) 
        {
            static::$onlyInstance = new Mail;
        }

        return static::$onlyInstance;
    }

    /**
     * set from 
     * @param string $var
     * @return \Mail
     */
    public static function from($var) 
    {
        static::$from = $var;
        return static::getself();
    }

    /**
     * set to
     * @param string $var
     * @return \Mail
     */
    public static function to($var) 
    {
        static::$to = $var;
        return static::getself();
    }

    /**
     * set subject
     * @param string $var
     * @return \Mail
     */
    public static function subject($var) 
    {
        static::$subject = $var;
        return static::getself();
    }

    /**
     * set message
     * @param string $var
     * @return \Mail
     */
    public static function message($var) 
    {
        static::$message = $var;
        return static::getself();
    }

    public static function send()
    {
        echo "<pre><b>Hurrah mail sent</b>"
                . "\nFrom:\t ".static::$from.""
                . "\nTo:\t ".static::$to." "
                . "\nSubject: ".static::$subject.""
                . "\nMessage: ".static::$message;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
Mail::from('george@garcha')
        ->to('michel@tome')
        ->subject('hehe works')
        ->message('your welcome')
        ->send();
```

**Output**

```
Hurrah mail sent
From:    george@garcha
To:      michel@tome 
Subject: hehe works
Message: your welcome
```

**Example 2 (*this also works*):**

```
    Mail::from('george@garcha')
        ->to('michel@tome');

    Mail::subject('hehe works')
        ->message('your welcome')
        ->send();
```